# Apache redirects form server aliases even though it apparently shouldn't

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, redirect, dns

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139889/multiple-domains-for-one-site-alias-or-redirect), Apache *should not* simply redirect from other ServerAlias domains to the ServerName domain, but in my case, it does.

For example, when I access www.yannbane.net, which is one of my domains point to my server's IP, it redirects me to yannbane.com. When I access www.yannbane.com, it redirects to yannbane.com as well.

This is the behavior that I actually want, but I don't understand what's happening here!

Here's my site's config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yannbane.com
    ServerAlias yannbane.net yannbane.org www.yannbane.net www.yannbane.org www.yannbane.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/yannbane.com/wordpress"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/yannbane.com/wordpress/error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's apache2.conf:

```
ServerName localhost

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default    
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Here's my .htaccess in my WordPress directory (which is the document root for this virtual host):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone tell me why are these redirects happening? And what's the appropriate way of achieving such behavior?

Comment: You may have extra related configuration in `.htaccess` files as you have an `AllowOverride All` from `/var/www`

Comment: Probably, but how exactly would I investigate that? In either case I've added my WordPress `.htaccess` file contents to the question now...

Comment: Wordpress does this, nothing to do with the Apache configuration. As I don't run WP, poke around in it's configuration and see if you can disable that. (You could even test this: make a static test.html page, and I'll bet good money that doesn't get redirected as it is not run through WP's framework).

Comment: @Wrikken - why don't you post that as an answer so I can accept it? I've just checked it and yes, WordPress is performing redirects. I can change this in the main settings section, so it could theoretically point to `www.yannbane.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in .htaccess to redirect the domain with www

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Actually this will help to redirect on new domain, here we can use www.yannbane.com instead of  www.newdomain,

http://techietent.blogspot.in/2013/03/url-redirection-using-htaccess.html